# Как можно улучшить код: «Ввести текст из файла набор предложений»?

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

Дали тестовое задание:

Ввести текст из файла набор предложений. Каждое предложение в
отдельной строке, слова разделены пробелом. Вывести количество слов во
всех предложениях, начиная со второго, в которых есть хотя бы одно
слово из первого предложения.

Так же выдает дубликаты в результатах:

```
(11)Жизнь — это больница, где каждый пациент мечтает перебраться на другую кровать.

(13)Жизнь не в том, чтобы жить, а в том, чтобы чувствовать, что живешь.

(13)Жизнь не в том, чтобы жить, а в том, чтобы чувствовать, что живешь.
```

Ниже моя реализация. Пожалуйста, подскажите, можно ли улучшить мой код? Если да, как это сделать? Пожалуйста, укажите почему то, что вы рекомендуете является улучшением?

TextFromFile

```
package main.java;

public class TextFromFile {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ReadFromFile().read();
  }
}
```

ReadFromFile

```
package main.java;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadFromFile {

  private final String FILE_NAME = "src/main/resources/text.txt";
  private List<String> stringsText;
  private String firstSentence;
  private String[] firstSentenceArray;

  public void read() {

    stringsText = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner in = null;
    try {
      in = new Scanner(new File(FILE_NAME));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (in.hasNext()){
      firstSentence = in.nextLine() + "\r\n";
      firstSentenceArray = firstSentence
          .replaceAll("[^а-яА-Я a-zA-Z]", " ")
          .replaceAll("\\s+", " ")
          .split(" ");
    }

    while(in.hasNext()) {
      String str = in.nextLine() + "\r\n";
      stringsText.add(str);
    }
    in.close();

    WordSearch wordSearch = new WordSearch();
    for (String aStringsText : firstSentenceArray) {
      stringsText.forEach(text -> wordSearch.wordsearch(text, aStringsText));
    }
  }
}
```

WordSearch.java

```
package main.java;

public class WordSearch {

  public void wordsearch(String text, String searchText) {
    String tt = text.replace("—", "")
        .replace("-", "")
        .replace(",", "");
    String[] textArray = tt.split(" ");

    for (String word : textArray) {
      if (searchText.equalsIgnoreCase(word)){
        String result = tt.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
        int cnt = result.split(" ").length;
        System.out.print("(" + cnt + ")");
        System.out.println(text);
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
>   e.printStackTrace();
> }
> ```

После этого выполнение [продолжится](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/740062/178988) и всё свалится на if из-за null.

> ```
> firstSentenceArray = firstSentence
>     .replaceAll("[^а-яА-Я a-zA-Z]", " ")
>     .replaceAll("\\s+", " ")
>     .split(" ");
> ```

Какая-то муть. Что мешает делать одну замену по регулярке, а не две? Что мешает сразу делать split по регулярке? Что если строка начинается или заканчивается пробелом?

> ```
> private final String FILE_NAME = "src/main/resources/text.txt";
> ```

Кажется, эту строку надо передавать в конструктор.

---

Ну и всё, что в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/739259/178988) @vp_arth.

Answer (score 2):

Токенизировать слова лучше так: `.split("\\P{L}+")`.

То, что вы по разному интерпретируете понятие "слово" в первом и остальных предложениях - это косяк. Тут должна быть консистентность - вынесите токенизацию в отдельный метод.

Алгоритмическая сложность квадратична(линейный `wordSearch`  в цикле по `firstSentenceArray`).
Проверку наличия слова в первом предложении можно сделать за константное время, если применить подходящую структуру данных(HashSet, например).

Про "выдаёт дубликаты в результатах" - это ещё косяк вашей реализации - вы никак не реагируете на то, что нашли слово в предложении и идёте дальше.

---

На мой взгляд реализация должна выглядеть как-то так(псевдокод):

```
sentence = readSentence();
map = tokenize(sentence);
while (hasInput()) {
  sentence = readSentence();
  words = tokenize(sentence);
  for (word in words) {
    if (map.contains(word)) {
      print words.length, sentence;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, хочу отметить, что у вас распух readfile. Это же по факту read-and-parse-and-something-and-and.... Для начала дайте корректное имя, отражающее смысл действий, а потом задумайтесь о декомпозиции на отдельные примитивы, чтобы не было слишком много ответственностей в одном месте.

Во-вторых, не надо хардкодить параметры! Почему имя файла не параметр, а константа?

В-третьих, давайте переменным осмысленные имена. Окей, я сразу понял, что такое firstSentence, это хороший образец. А что такое 'in'? Я думал, думал... И нашел! Это (неожиданно) сканер! Давайте так: на заборе должно быть написано "дрова" и лежать там должны тоже дрова

Comment: Оффтопик: в java не спец, писал из общих соображений, второпях из метро с мобилы, потом перечмтаю и поправлю.

Comment: Ну зачем же вы на `in` накинулись? Нормальное имя для входного потока данных.

Comment: Так себе ревью. Только со вторым пунктом согласен при текущем написании.